# Magnific Popup - Counter in Videogallery

Tags: magnific-popup

I made a video gallery with magnific popup.

But unlike the imagegallery, the videogallery doesn't show a counter e.g. **1/3** at the bottom right of the video. Why not? In the imagegallery it works well.

Code of the Videogallery:

```
$('.gallery_video').each(function() { // the containers for all your galleries
    $(this).magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a', // the selector for gallery item
        disableOn: 700,
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: true,
        fixedContentPos: false,
        gallery: {
          enabled:true
        },
        callbacks: {
      lazyLoad: function(item) {
        console.log(item); // Magnific Popup data object that should be loaded
      }
    }
    });
});
```

Code of imagegallery:

```
$('.image-popup-no-margins').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    closeBtnInside: true,
    fixedContentPos: true,
    mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
    image: {
        verticalFit: true
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
    },
    callbacks: {
      lazyLoad: function(item) {
        console.log(item); // Magnific Popup data object that should be loaded
      }
    }
});
```

Both scripts don't specify a counter so why isn't it showing up on both?

thank you

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm only using one function to call both the iframe or image type, using the type: image by default in my script and passing the class="mfp-iframe" on the anchor tag of a video to force the type change. My .mpf-counter div completely disappears when the video is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been a time ago when this was asked but a full anwser:

You have to add or specify the iframe markup.
You also want to add some small css updates for positioning the counter.

```js
var $attachmentContainers = $('.js-attachments-in-gallery');

$attachmentContainers.magnificPopup({
  delegate: 'a',
  type: 'image',
  gallery:{
    enabled:true,
  },
  iframe: {
    markup:
    '<div class="mfp-iframe-scaler">'+
      '<div class="mfp-close"></div>'+
        '<iframe class="mfp-iframe" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'+
        '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar">'+
        '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'+
      '</div>'+
    '</div>'
  }
});
```

```css
.mfp-iframe-scaler .mfp-bottom-bar {
  margin-top: 4px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - for the iframe type you have to specify that you want a counter:

```
$(this).magnificPopup({
.....
iframe: {
             markup: '<button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button>'+
                '<div class="mfp-counter"></div>'
}
```